# View full size images inline in Gmail (they appear small to fit in within the email)

Tags: gmail

Sometimes I receive an email with an inline image in Gmail. I have to right click the image and paste into an external app, like Paint, to see it full size.

Is there any way to zoom this from within Gmail, without having to go to an external app?

When I paste the image into Paint, I don't have to zoom or anything, it is already full-size; it is as if Gmail makes it smaller just so it all fits nicely in the email.

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on the image and choose open in new tab, or click on the image, or click on the *View* link next to the image it will be opened in a new browser tab and shown full size.

Comment: Sometimes it opens in browser tab, but sometimes it downloads (I don't want it downloading as then we are back to paint pasting again).

Comment: If you choose right-click -> open in new tab it shouldn't download it. What browser are you using?

Comment: Sometimes even when you right click | open in new tab, it sill downloads, I'm using Google Chrome (latest version).

Comment: I've never encountered that issue. Every time I chose `Open image in new tab` Chrome opens a new tab with the image. What format is the image that gets downloaded?